# Webkit GTK: Exposing HTTP headers

Tags: c, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

After experimenting with WebkitGTK in C, and looking through the [documentation](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html), I see that most of the signals/events relating to the loading of webpages are oriented around when a page begins loading or finishes loading.

However, I don't see anyway that the actual HTTP headers of a request are exposed.  Therefore, I don't see anyway to detect, for example, if `webkit_web_view_load_uri` loaded a page with a 404 error.  The error reporting mechanisms seem only concerned with *network errors*, rather than HTTP errors.  In fact, I don't see anything to do with HTTP exposed in the WebkitGTK API at all.

Am I just missing something here?  I even grepped the entire `webkit` include directory for `http` and `HTTP` and nothing relevant comes up.  So is there some way to determine whether a downloaded page is an HTTP error (some other error code other than `200 OK`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKit is just the layout engine, and does not include HTTP support.  In the WebKitGTK port HTTP is handled by libsoup.  You get the `SoupSession` using `webkit_get_default_session` and proceed from there.